# How to selectively log specific modules in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, module

I am trying to log some modules selectively into a file. Here are the four modules

operation.py

```
from addition import Addition
from subtraction import Subtraction
import logmodule

logmodule.set_logger(__name__)

n1 = -3
n2 = 1
add_res = Addition(n1,n2)
sub_res = Subtraction(n1,n2)

logmodule.logger.info('The numbers are {} and {}'. format(n1,n2))
logmodule.track_module('subtraction')
#logmodule.track_module('addition')

add_res.add(n1,n2)
sub_res.subtract(n1,n2)
```

addition.py

```
import logmodule

class Addition():

    def __init__(self,num1,num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        logmodule.logger.debug('The numbers are {} and {}'. format(num1,num2))

    def add(self,num1,num2):
        result = self.num1 + self.num2
        logmodule.logger.info('The result of addition is {}'. format(result))
```

subtraction.py

```
import logmodule

class Subtraction():

    def __init__(self,num1,num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        logmodule.logger.debug('The numbers are {} and {}'. format(num1,num2))

    def subtract(self,num1,num2):
        if(num2 > num1):
            logmodule.logger.warning("num2 is greater than num1")

        result = self.num1-self.num2
        logmodule.logger.info('The result of subtraction zis {}'. format(result))
```

logmodule.py

```
import logging


def _init_logger():
    lg = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    lg.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
    return lg


logger = _init_logger()
LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s\t%(levelname)-8s\t%(module)s:\t%(message)s'
_log_modules = []

 


def set_logger(name: str, logfile = "math.log"):

    global logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
    fmt = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT)

    handler.setFormatter(fmt)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    open(logfile, 'w')#.close()

def track_module(module_name: str):
    """Sets a given module to be tracked by logger."""

    global _log_modules
    _log_modules.append(module_name)
```

When I try to log only one module say subtraction by the line `logmodule.track_module('subtraction')`in operation.py module, both addition and subtraction modules are getting logged. What can i do to fix it ?